# What key restrictions are possible for additionalProperties in OpenAPI 3?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am looking at an OpenAPI specification which makes use of `additionalProperties` to create a schema that maps user-specified names to objects (the type of object is unimportant). Here is a simplified example of what it is doing:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    CityData:
      type: object
      properties:
        population:
          type: integer
        is_capital:
          type: boolean
    Country:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        cities:
          type: object
          description: A mapping of city names to data about those cities
          additionalProperties:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/CityData'
```

So an example of a `Country` object would be:

```json
{ "name": "Germany", "cities": { "Essen": { "population": 583109, "is_capital": false } } }
```

I know that I can place limits to require that each country has a minimum or maximum number of cities, by using `minProperties` and `maxProperties`. Is there a way to place any restrictions on the property keys themselves (the city names, in the above example)? For example, what if I wanted to ensure that a city name had between 1-100 characters? Is it possible to restrict the length of the property keys with `additionalProperties`?

I realize that this example could be refactored so that the city names were an explicit string property inside of the `CityData` schema, in which case it would then be straightforward to impose these restrictions using `minLength` and `maxLength`. I am working with an existing schema where I do not have the freedom to do such refactoring.

Is any way to encode these restrictions in OpenAPI 3, or if the best that can be done is to verbally communicate them (in the description text, for example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? -- [How to write OpenAPI 3 specification for property name in `map` object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46552863/113116)