# use an enum as a key in a map using OpenAPI spec

Tags: openapi

I would like to create a parameter in OpenAPI spec which is a Map<Enum,String>
Is there a way to define the key as an enum or is it restricted to only strings?

Comment: See if this answers your question -- [How to write OpenAPI 3 (Swagger) specification for property name in `map` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46553255/113116). The 2nd example there (the one with `propertyNames`) covers enums as map keys.