# How to define an object with arbitrary keys, but fixed key and value types?

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-3-0

How would you define an object in OpenAPI 3.x when the keys can be any value, but always a specific format, with a similar requirement for values?

For example the following structure

`keyValues: {"a": ["1", "2"], "b": ["3"]}`

might be defined as

```yaml
properties:
  keyValues:
    type: object
    keys:
      type: string
    values:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
```

Comment: [`additionalProperties`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? -- [How to write OpenAPI 3 specification for property name in `map` object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46552863/113116)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using `additionalProperties`. The `string` type of the object keys seems to be implicit since [JSON only supports strings for keys](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html).

```
keyValues:
  description: "A `string:[string]` object of key-values."
  type: object
  additionalProperties:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
```